# i can't get the div out of normal flow, it stays below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add a "contact" card to the website's right-top and sticky, but i have a div there so it's blocking the contact card. how can i fix that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/umC7B.jpg

```
<div class="card card-contact">
        <div class="card-header"><h2>Social Media</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body"><p class="body-card">
            Facebook, Instagram, Twitter 
        </div>
</div>

---CSS---

.card-contact{
    width: 20rem;
    height: auto;
}

.body-card {
    font-size: 1rem;   
}
```

Comment: where did you added the sticky and the `top: 0;`to actually have it stick at the top?

Comment: to card-contact class but it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap 4 or above you can edit your code like this  so as to make your card sticky to top right

```css
.card-contact{
  width: 20rem;
  height: auto;
  }

.body-card {
  font-size: 1rem;   
}

.main-card{
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 }
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-4 main-card ">
               <div class="card card-contact">
                   <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>Social Media</h2>
                   </div>
                   <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="body-card">
                        Facebook, Instagram, Twitter
                        </p>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
</section>
```